# Session Start not working in godaddy

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies, session-state

This code worked in my local Sever but its not working in Godaddy. I
 use a header file inside Includes and include it in all the other
files.

> **Error: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers
>   already sent by (output started at
>   /home/safetrade/public_html/Includes/header.php:13) in
>   /home/safetrade/public_html/trade-plan.php on line 4**

**Code in my header.php file**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>   
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Safetrade Bitcoins</title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

**This is a code in trade-plan.php**

```
<?php include"Includes/header.php" ?>
<?php
 if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])) { 
    header("location:register.php");
}
?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-trade.css">

</head>
<body>
```

when I remove this

```
<?php
 if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])) { 
    header("location:register.php");
}
?>
```

Code in trade-plan.php it worked fine.still I can't validate using isset.

Comment: This seems unrelated to sessions, most likely you have an unrelated errors at the beginning of your code, which prevents the session handler to start. Check what's at /home/safetrade/public_html/Includes/header.php:13

Comment: share the code of `header.php`

Comment: Change `<?php include"Includes/header.php" ?>` to `<?php require "Includes/header.php" ?>` DO you now get any errors

Comment: Are you sure the directory name is `Includes` with a capital `I`. Remember Unix is case sensitive

Comment: Warning: require(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/safetrade/public_html/trade-plan.php on line 1

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '1' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php') in /home/safetrade/public_html/trade-plan.php on line 1 @riggsFolly

http://www.safetradebitcoins.com/trade-plan.php

Comment: Yes my directory name is Includes with capitial I

Comment: @AshiqurRahuman thats all the code i have in header.